# Should I use Wordpress or code it myself?

Tags: php, html, sql, project, profile

I am creating a community website where I want users who sign up to be able to create their own profile with options that I provides for them such as

Abilities to add
 - Avatar (Profile Pictures)
 - Customized Username (Only once and will be used in forum)(Be able to change if enough XP)
 - Post Status Updates (Can be seen by friends/everyone)
 - Add links to their profile
 - Create a bio
 - Add tabs to profile such as Profile/Games/Work/Videos/Other (You can choose)
 - Will have stats for forum posts, profile views, forum post views and more.
 - Can message/add friend/remove friend/block/unblock/report 
 - XP points for profile completion
 - Contact Info (Choose from list or add your own)
 - Show your team stats/profile on page (Must have a team page on our website.)

It's just features I would like to add/learn to code in the future of the website. Just concern but before going any futher, is there any other websites like Wordpress that is already made and have abilities to do all of above and other stuff. If not, I don't really mind but really want to learn to code. What kind of codes do I need to know for all of this, such as PHP, Javascript, MySQL, and any other?

Also upgrades for those who earn certain XP points where they can upgrade their profile. Maybe even purchase XP points to add to their account.

If buying upgrades such as
 - Change username color (Take effect on profile, forum, and more)
 - Buy username effects (Affect profile, forum, and more)
 - Add a profile banner (Where you can upload for advertisement.)
 - No ads (Certain amount of time or forever)(Must be logged in)
 - Change username

Would be using:
 - Dreamweaver CS6
 - Notepad C++
 - Photoshop CS6
Anything else I would need?

There are so much more features I would like to add but I just want to know what kind of coding I would need to learn to make my project work. It may take a year or less but it's a goal. Please help me out.

Thank You
Joseph Scott

Comment: Welcome to SO. This kind of question does not really fit here as 'best' is generally a matter of opinion, and so not constructive. We like questions that have 1 answer. Unfortunately this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Possible self-duplicate of: [Should I start my website scratch or other options?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037705/should-i-start-my-website-scratch-or-other-options)

Comment: I couldn't delete it and decided to make another post since my last one wasn't clear. It was a mistaken post and wasn't very well clear.

Comment: @VisualizeEdits: You're welcome. But this question here is borderline as well. Keep in mind that even if you get an answer you can only gain as much from it as much as your question really talks about your problem. If you've got software design questions, better user the programmers site: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sorry and I'm new here and had no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer configuration and tweaking around an out-of-the-box system, and like PHP in case coding becomes necessary, than take Drupal. It is widely used and has a configurable module for each of your requirements (Avatar, user points ect.), and works out of the box. But upgrading might become a nightmare, and passing a certain level of customization can more easily done with frameworks like Django.

If you like to code Python, configuration on file system level, much coding from the beginning, Django is the preferred choice from my point of view, as it provides most flexibility and has proven itself on many live sites. But getting something started takes at least a month, while with Drupal you have something up and running withing a day or two.

I suggest have a look at Drupal first, collecting the modules you need, it just makes fun. But keep in mind that customizing and maintaining it for more than two years is more work than doing it with Django from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way I can message you? (privately)

Comment: Drupal look really great and I agree on the part about getting started. I am about to start on the HTML/CSS for the home page of my website and then start fixing the login/registering system I guess using the MySQL's database system and PHP. I may have questions though if you are willing to help me.

Comment: I like your way of just jumping into the topic. But keep in mind using a framework or CMS, like Django or Drupal, you need to do it the framework way. This means before you start customizing a little thing, you must read the documentation or search on web about how to do it the way the framework is expecting it ("the best way to do it in the Drupal way", for example). Otherwise you won't be able to even update to the next security release … If you choose Drupal, its community is great and when it comes to the details, I am sure people there can help you better than I could do.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into Drupal and learn more such as how it work.

Answer (score 0):

> Use Cimy User extra fields plugin can provides you all kind of custom inputs..even if you created a custom registration page also..
>
> go through this link to grab this plugin :
>
> http://wordpress.org/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/

Comment: Thank you very much! I would look into this if I decided to use Wordpress but I just don't like the theme much and I have my own theme/designs I am creating and don't think Wordpress will be best suited. http://gyazo.com/48375c81f920c727a071cdd45a331065

Comment: Alryt.. if this answer is fine for you rate this answer. To accept you just need to click on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's scoreplease

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Phpfox over Wordpress.

Comment: Is it like a big script that I can add to my website coding. I looked at it but I don't know if I can tweak the code to make it blend into my website. I have a forum I would like to make kinda like MyBB and PhpBB but I would want the login system to be the same as the forum with the username and postbit from profile.